# Delete row from Datagridview and Access [Thesis Making]

Tags: c#, datagridview

So, I am trying to delete a row but it keeps on appearing

[image]

my codes are

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dtgAccs.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            if (dtgAccs.CurrentRow.Index == dtgAccs.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please re-select rows.");
            }
            else
            {
                if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show(("Delete Account?"), "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
                {
                    dtgAccs.Rows.RemoveAt(dtgAccs.CurrentRow.Index);
                    db.execSQL("DELETE from Accounts WHERE ID='" + IDa + "'AND Full_Name ='" + FullN + "'AND Email ='"
                        + Emaila + "'AND User_name ='" + Usernamea + "'AND Pass_word ='" + Passworda + "'AND Position_a ='" + Positiona + "'" );
                    MessageBox.Show("Account has been deleted.");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Account to delete.");
        }
    }
```

I'm a newbie and idk how so XD help me maybe? Thanks in advance

BTW XD if you have a code sample to show me or edit my codes, it would be appreciated. sprry for being a newbie huhuhu

Comment: Error is in your execSQL command. check your parameters

Comment: Not a good choiche to make pressure to get an answer. You risk to get only downvotes and closure votes. However you should start looking at the difference between strings and numbers. Your database expects a number  but you pass only strings

Comment: I'm sorry I'm sorry XD not in a rush really, but, what should I use? Hmm. I use Access as my database, and I'm not really expert at this XD it's my thesis and my groupmates are useless

Comment: Should I replace something from the WHERE statement?

Comment: IM SORRY FROM THE ASAP THINGY, not a rush really XD how can i remove it?

Comment: Look at your database fields used in the WHERE statement. Are they all of text datatype? If not you can't pass a string for them (putting a value between single quotes is wrong on many levels but essentially transform your value in a string where a different type is expected)

Comment: By the way, does the Account table have many records with the same ID or that field is the primary key of your table?

Comment: Hiii Steve, uhmm.. ID is Primary and AutoNumber, the only number, the rest are LongTest datatype in Access

Comment: Then you don't need them in the WHERE clause and the ID value could be passed without enclosing it within single quotes. For example: int IDa = 12;  .... _"DELETE from Accounts WHERE ID=" + IDa.ToString()_

Comment: Like this?

` if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show(("Delete Account?"), "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
                    {
                        dtgAccs.Rows.RemoveAt(dtgAccs.CurrentRow.Index);
                        db.execSQL("DELETE from Accounts WHERE ID=" + IDa.ToString());
                        MessageBox.Show("Account has been deleted.");
                    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer now. Thanks to my instructor for helping me what to do XD

```
 if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show(("Delete Account?"), "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
                {
                    int userId = Convert.ToInt32(dtgAccs.Rows[dtgAccs.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value);
                    Console.Write(userId);


                    db.execSQL("DELETE from Accounts WHERE ID=" + userId);


                    dtgAccs.Rows.RemoveAt(dtgAccs.CurrentRow.Index);

                    MessageBox.Show("Account has been deleted.");
                }
```

You just gotta make a variable and convert it :) Hope this helps for others too